# Why strtotime is not working appropriately?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I wanted to convert the code $txt into 24 hours format

```
$txt = "12:40:22AM";

echo date("G:i:s",strtotime($txt));
```

got output

```
0:40:22
```

Comment: Are you sure that is a format strtotime can parse?

Comment: 24 hour format has either 0 or 24 for the midnight hour. 12 would be noon. G is 24 hour format, H is 12 hour format. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: @aynber I'm aware of it but Just wanted to test it with strtotime that it should print 12:40:22, not 0:40:22.

Comment: 12AM is midnight, not noon! 12:40AM -> 00.40 and 12:40PM -> 12.40

Comment: @user1915746 I got it I have resolved my problem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

try use H instead of G in the format definition.

```
$txt = "5:40:22AM";
$t = date("H:i:s",strtotime($txt));
echo $t;
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried it with H it's working with my problem statement.